# Is there any logic behind naming Android OS after food items?

Tags: android

What is logic behind naming Android OS after food items?

Android 2.2     Froyo ;
Android 2,3     GingerBread ;
Android 3.0     Honeycomb ;
Android 4.0     Ice cream sandwidth ;
Android 4.2     Jelly Bean ;
Android 4.4     Kitkat

On what basis these list is added? Any conventions applied here?

Comment: *F*royo. *G*ingerbread. *H*oneycomb. *I*cecream Sandwich. *J*elly Bean. *K*itkat. I see a pattern.

Comment: Ask this question to **Google**... Only **Google** better to know.....

Comment: They are such gluttons!! Anyway, this question appears to be off-topic because it is **not about programming**

Answer (score 2):

From [Why does Google name its Android products after desserts?](http://www.cnn.com/2011/TECH/innovation/02/04/google.honeycomb.android.names/):

> **Google doesn't want to explain.**
>
> "It's kind of like an internal team thing, and we prefer to be a
>   little bit -- how should I say -- a bit inscrutable in the matter,
>   I'll say," said Randall Sarafa, a Google spokesman. "The obvious thing
>   is that, yeah, the Android platform releases, they go by dessert names
>   **and by alphabetical order for the most part.**"
>
> "For the most part" because two versions of Android, 2.0 and 2.1, were
>   both called Eclair. And because Google won't say what it called the
>   first two versions of Android, which you can assume started with "A"
>   and "B."

Also check [Trivia: Why Does Google Name Its OS after Desserts?](http://www.androidauthority.com/trivia-why-does-google-name-its-os-after-desserts-42822/)